# First countable compact spaces are sequentially compact, how weaker assumption ease the proof?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

[A first countable, countably compact space is sequentially compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812531/a-first-countable-countably-compact-space-is-sequentially-compact)

José Carlos Santos's answer

> Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of elements of $X$. There are two possibilities:
>
> 1. There is some $x\in X$ such that $x_n=x$ for infinitely many $n$'s. Then it is obvious that $x$ is a limit of a subsequence of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.
> 2. For every $x\in X$, the equality $x_n=x$ holds for finitely many $n$'s only. In that case, the set $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ is infinite. Since $X$ is limit point compact, there is some $x\in X$ which is a limit of a sequence of elements of $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$. Therefore, $x$ is a limit of some subsequence of the sequence $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$.

I cannot really see if we have one more assumption such as **Compactness** not **Countably Compactness**, how this assumption ease the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof for a compact space is exactly the same, we need only that for a countably infinite subset $A$ there is a strong limit point i. e. a $p \in X$ such that for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$ we have that $A\cap O$ is infinite. It is well-known that countable compactness is equivalent to this fact.

In either case we then proceed to exploit the first countability at $p$ to construct the required convergent subsequence to $p$.

Compactness does not help the proof at all. But as compactness implies countable compactness the theorem is stated with the weakest assumption only.

Comment: [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812737/4280) to the linked question explains it in more detail even. The quoted answer omits some subtle details and can be confusing.