# We know that the space given below is countably compact . But how can i prove that X is not sequentially compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let X be the product of  [0 , $\Omega$) with the interval topology and $I^I$ with the cartesian product topology , where $I$ is  unit interval.

Comment: $X$ **is** weakly countably compact: every countably compact space is. $X$ is not sequentially compact, since it contains a closed subspace homeomorphic to $I^I$, which is a well-known example of a compact space that is not sequentially compact.

Comment: Which closed subspace of X is homeomorphic to $I^I$

Comment: Every subspace of the form $\{\alpha\}\times I^I$, among many others.

Answer (score 1):

$[0,\Omega)$ is countably compact (a countable open cover has a finite subcover), and a product of a countably compact space and a compact space (i.e. $I^I$) is still countably compact. So $X$ is countably compact, and so also weakly countably compact (every infinite set has a limit point in $X$); this implication always holds (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812737/4280)). $X$ is however not sequentially compact, because $\{0,1\}^I$ is a closed subset of it, and would then *also* be sequentially compact, which it is not (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1558796/4280)).

Of course $\{0,1\}^I$ (or $I^I$) by itself is already an example of a (countably) compact space that is not sequentially compact, but $X$ is also non-compact, which might have been the "point" of this example.

Comment: sir ...Give me a proof of above example which is not sequentially compact

Comment: @MukeshSuthar i gave the proof that it was not sequentially compact didn’t I ? What do you mean?

Comment: Hello sir..in your proof $I$ is a product of two point set but in my question $I$ is closed unit interval [ 0 , 1 ]

Comment: @MukeshSuthar it’s a closed subset of $I^I$ so that makes no difference. E.g. If $X$ is seq. compact, so is $I^I$ then so is $\{0,1\}^I$, and this is a product of continuum many two point spaces (for which I show in the link it is *not* seq. compact).

Comment: Hello sir...If you have any other simple proof for that $X=[0,\Omega) \times I^I $ is not sequentially compact ...please share with me..

Comment: @MukeshSuthar The closed set argument, reducing to $\{0,1\}^I$, is the simplest one IMO.

Comment: But i can't understand that what you can say here exactly ?

Comment: @MukeshSuthar What's your point? That's the whole proof. You just need to know that a closed subset of a sequentially compact space is again sequentially compact and reason by contradiction, as I showed.

Comment: That means in your proof..First we assume that $X=[0,\Omega) \times I^I $ is sequentially compact and after we will use the cosed subspace of sequentially compact space is sequentially compact and we get contradiction . So original space X is not sequentially compact

Comment: @MukeshSuthar right.

Comment: @MukeshSuthar $\{0,1\}^I$ is a closed subspace of $[0,1]^I$ which is homeomorphic to $\{0\} \times I^I$ which is a closed subspace of $X$.

Comment: Ok...Thank you sir....

Comment: Under which homeomorphism $\{0,1/}^{I}$ and $\{ 0 /} /times I^{I} $ are homeomorphic.

Comment: @MukeshSuthar the obvious one...

Comment: But under which homeomorphism both are homeomorphic..give me a homeomorphism

Comment: $I^I$ is homeomorphic to $\{0\} \times I^I \subseteq X$ by $f(x)=(0,x)$ of course.