# Countable intersection of nested non-empty closed sets in ZF

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

> For all sequences of nested (non-increasing with respect to set-inclusion) non-empty closed sets, their intersection is non-empty.

What are the minimum conditions on a topological space for it to satisfy this property in ZF (without any choice)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This true iff every countable open cover has a finite subcover. The proof involves just taking complements and noting that if $U_n$ is any sequence of open sets then  $U_1 \cup U_2\cup...\cup U_n$ is an increasing sequence of open sets whose union is the same as the union of the $U_i$'s.

Comment: It is customary these days for an answer to also have some mathematical justifications behind it, and not just a comment. Especially coming from someone with nearly 100k in reputation.

Comment: Being elementary does not mean that it shouldn't be said. On the contrary, if the proof is so short, what's your excuse for not writing it in the first place?

Comment: Such spaces are called [countably compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space)

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1817493/4280) I show it is equivalent to the fact that every infinite subset $A$ of $X$ has an $\omega$-limit point. But in the proof I think I use (countable) dependent choice, and this might well be essential. So under ZF I'm not sure the equivalence will hold...@AsafKaragila

Comment: @Henno: To my knowledge this is somewhere in the vicinity of countable choice, or at least "every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite". Requiring countable covers to have finite subcovers seem to circumvent this issue directly.