# Why does a Hausdorff but not countably compact space have an infinite closed discrete subset?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Why does a Hausdorff but not countably compact space have an infinite closed discrete subset?

In the proof of Theorem 2.1.5 in

- *E. K. van Douwen, G. M. Reed, A. W. Roscoe, and I. J. Tree*, MR 1103993 [**Star covering properties**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(91)90077-Y), *Topology Appl.* **39** (1991), no. 1, 71--103.

the authors prove that a star compact Hausdorff space is countably compact. At the start of the proof they write

> Suppose that $X$ is a Hausdorff space that is not countably compact. Then there exists $D = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb N \} \subseteq X$, an infinite closed discrete subset.

I do not understand why if $X$ is Hausdorff but not countably compact, then there is an infinite closed discrete $D$.

Comment: I deleted an answer because I realized I had overlooked "closed" so it was at least incomplete, possibly worse (e.g. misleading). I'm pretty sure the way I got a discrete infinite set could give a nonclosed one.

Answer (score 3):

In Hausdorff (in fact T<sub>1</sub>) spaces, countable compactness is equivalent to *limit point compactness*. Recall the definition:

- A topological space $X$ is *limit point compact* if every infinite $A \subseteq X$ has a limit point, that is, there is an $x \in X$ such that each open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ different from $x$ itself.

(For a proof see the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1360019).)

If $X$ is a Hausdorff space which is not countably compact, there is an infinite subset $D \subseteq X$ with no limit points. It is easy to show that such a set is closed and discrete:

- For each $x \in D$, since $x$ is not a limit point of $X$, then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which contains so other points of $D$, *i.e.*, $U \cap D = \{ x \}$. So $D$ is discrete.
- Recall that $\overline{D} = D \cup \{ x \in X : x \text{ is a limit point of } D \}$. Since $D$ has no limit points it follows that $D = \overline{D}$, and so it is closed.